# TypeError: context must be a dict rather than set

Tags: python, html, django, web-applications

I am trying to combine these two views. This is what I have. MenuView is to combine with add_to_menu so that if the if statement returns negative, the menuview portion still runs and displays the menu on my html page. If the if statement is positive, it still shows the menu, but also adds the entered information into the database. I can only get one or the other to work at a time.

Edit: Ok I figured out that it was just stupid white-space that I was using, but I am still having issues combining the two views.

Views.py:

```
class MenuView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'mis446/edit-menu.html'
    context_object_name = 'show_menu'


def add_to_menu(request):

   if request.method == 'POST':
       if request.POST.get('name') and request.POST.get('price') and request.POST.get('nickname'):
        post=Product()
        post.name= request.POST.get('name')
        post.price= request.POST.get('price')
        post.slug= request.POST.get('nickname')
        post.save()
        model = Product
        context_object_name = {'show_menu'}
        return render(request, 'mis446/edit-menu.html', context_object_name)  

   else:
        model = Product
        context_object_name = {'show_menu'}
        return render(request,'mis446/edit-menu.html')
```

Comment: context_object_name is a set not a dictionary

Comment: How do I change it to a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check the spaces in the indentation. I mean there should be a tab space and not 4 spaces and it seems like in your second if statement there's a single space instead of a tab space. Consider it doing this way

```
class MenuView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'mis446/edit-menu.html'
    context_object_name = 'show_menu'


def add_to_menu(request):

   if request.method == 'POST':
       if request.POST.get('name') and request.POST.get('price') and request.POST.get('nickname'):
           post=Product()
           post.name= request.POST.get('name')
           post.price= request.POST.get('price')
           post.slug= request.POST.get('nickname')
           post.save()
           model = Product
           context_object_name = {'show_menu'}
           return render(request, 'mis446/edit-menu.html', context_object_name)  

   else:
        model = Product
        context_object_name = {'show_menu'}
        return render(request,'mis446/edit-menu.html')
```